# Create a new page with wp_insert_post ()

Tags: wordpress

I have the following code in a PHP function that is activated when I install my plugin that lets you create a post or page.

Works perfect and make the page if the `$post_type` is "post", but if the `$post_type` is "page", then it does not work, does not create the page.:

```
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => 'My page Reql',
  'post_type'     => 'page',
  'post_name'     => 'my-page',
  'post_content'  => 'This is my page reql.',
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'comment_status' => 'closed',
  'ping_status' => 'closed',
  'post_author' => 1,
  'menu_order' => 0
);

wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

What is the problem? I can not find the solution.

Thank you very much!

Comment: what errors are showing up in your php error log?

Comment: User#1 allowed to post pages? post_title not already used? I tested it on one of my WP installs: it works perfectly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you have to set the `guid` too, like this

```
$PageGuid = site_url() . "/my-page-req1";
$my_post  = array( 'post_title'     => 'My page Reql',
                   'post_type'      => 'page',
                   'post_name'      => 'my-page',
                   'post_content'   => 'This is my page reql.',
                   'post_status'    => 'publish',
                   'comment_status' => 'closed',
                   'ping_status'    => 'closed',
                   'post_author'    => 1,
                   'menu_order'     => 0,
                   'guid'           => $PageGuid );

$PageID = wp_insert_post( $my_post, FALSE ); // Get Post ID - FALSE to return 0 instead of wp_error.
```

Comment: I appreciate this `soloution` may `work` but this seems like abuse of the `guid` field to me, why would you not just put a `guid` in the `guid` field? If there is something I have misunderstood then please explain, but for someone who knows what a guid is this seems like a hack. Would it not be better to use the wp_generate_uuid4() function provided by wordpress https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_uuid4/

Comment: I have just tried this soloution with and without a GUID it seems to work, without this sceneario so recommend to anyone to try without the GUID first