# How to create a non-admin page programmatically in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, drupal, menu

In Wordpress how can I define a custom path/menu and in the callback I want to add page content. In Drupal we have `hook_menu()` where we can define a menu path and in a callback we can add contents. Is there anything similar in Wordpress?

I found [admin_menu](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_menu) `add_action('admin_menu', 'custom_callback')` which creates an admin menu item. I want to create non-admin pages. How can I achieve it?

Comment: looks like a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848052/create-a-new-page-with-wp-insert-post

Answer (score 0):

You would use the `wp_insert_post()` function with the post type of `page`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/